# MySQL Multiple Colums Index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table. But in phpmyadmin; Something stuck in my head while creating the index. When you select and create more than one column, a single index is created for 3 columns.

How is this different from creating indexes on columns one by one?

Also, which columns makes more sense to create an index for the following query?

TABLE

| id | username | permalink | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Example | example | 1 |

QUERY

```mysql
SELECT * FROM table where permalink='example' and status='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an index, some operations will be slower (like insert), and you will consume more disk space and memory.

You should create an index on columns with high cardinality (columns with values that are very uncommon or unique) and that you use in WHERE clauses to make them faster.

For example for `permalink` column you should have an index, but not on `status` because of low cardinality. If you have 3 columns in your WHERE clause, it could be faster to have a compound index on all 3 columns.

```
.. WHERE column1 = 'a' AND column2 = 'b' AND column3 = 'c'
```

For starters, make individually indexes for the columns with high cardinality. After you have lots of data and the system starts to slow down, use the EXPLAIN SELECT ... query to find out that what indexes are used in your query. And then optimize using compound indexes if needed. I use tools like JetProfiler or NewRelic to monitor the system and find slow queries. You cannot anticipate everything from the start. Also, the MySQL slow query log is a good place to find what you need to optimize.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Actually, I know part of what you said (disk capacity, speed). What I'm wondering is the difference between the separately created directory and the combined directories. Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: If you have a compound index on 3 columns (column1, column2, colum3) and you make select with only WHERE column2 for example, it will not be used, and you will have to make a separat index for column2. Depends on you WHERE conditions.

Comment: Hmm, consider for example (event,month_permalink,year_permalink....) in another table. Some pages use only month_permalink, while others require only year_permalink. Imagine there are too many columns like this. (See: Wikipedia example)

In this case, the merged directory will not work. According to what you said, it is necessary to create separate indexes. This doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: For starters, make individually indexes for the columns with high cardinality. After you have lots of data and the system starts to slow down, use the EXPLAIN SELECT ... query  to find out that what indexes are used in your query. And then optimize using compound indexes if needed. I use tools like JetProfiler or NewRelic to monitor the system and find slow queries. You cannot anticipated everything  from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing a number **i** of columns together is done for queries that use combination of all **i** columns.

Let's say you have `table` with `column1` and `column2`. You should index both columns (first considering their type and their size) for queries like
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = something1 AND column2 = something2`.

Keep in mind that this is not always optimal to do (another answer explained why) :)